# ASPNETCOMPILER : error ASPRUNTIME: Target Directory not empty

Tags: .net, asp.net, build, nant

I have a web application that needs to be built using a nant script. All the projects in the solution build fine but for this error that crops up each time at the end of the build. I couldn't find much useful information on resolving this error. Has anyone encountered and fixed this kind of issue before? Any help would be much appreciated.

> [exec] ASPNETCOMPILER : error
>   ASPRUNTIME: The target directory is
>   not empty, and does not appear to
>   contain a previously compiled
>   application. Please delete it
>   manually, or choose a different
>   target.
>   [C:\SRC\BorgWorld\trunk\apps\Zombies.metaproj]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Delete the temporary website folder from

c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\

Comment: Also delete the contents of the same folder under Framework64: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files

Answer (score 14):

I got this to work by just deleting the folder to where the website was being precompiled. The nant succeeded with all projects built successfully.

Answer (score 4):

I got it working by deleting everything except the `.wdproj` file in the `deploy` folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was PrecompiledWeb folder in the solution root directory. The msbuild log points at it before complaining about the metaproj folder, which does not even exist in my case.